How Do I Install PIP Offline with Windows Python
UPDATE:
I guess my question never got posted because the site said it was related to an answered question, which it was not.
In any case, I figured it our on my own. The pip program is optionally installed when you install Python for Windows. While I did have it installed, it did not add it to my environmental path. I eventually figured out that it installs pip in the root python directory and in the subfolder scripts.
It ended up being an easy solution, but wasn't completely intuitive for a noob.
ORIGINAL:
I've found so many articles, but all of them rely on some other package that would also have to be downloaded.  I have downloaded Python 3.12 executable and installed it on my offline Windows machine.  I need the following packages:

six
psutil
lxml
pyopenssl

When attempting to install these offline, I've found some good articles, but they require pip.  So how do I install pip offline.  Please don't say "using setuptools, because I have nothing installed other than base Python.  If I need another package to install pip, then I need to know how to install that package offline as well.
Thank you in advance!
I tried installing pip using get-pip.py but found that this method requires an internet connection.
I found another method to download the pip-24.0 rar file and extract that, then run 'python setup.py install', but I get an error stating that the module 'setuptools' could not be found.

Your question was posted. It got closed because it very obviously is answered by the linked duplicate. Please read What does it mean if a question is "closed"? and Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance and "This question already has answers here" - but it does not. What can I do when I think a question is not a duplicate?.

I added another duplicate link for the problem of not finding Pip after installing it. This, too, is a commonly cited Q&A. (It also has more to do with understanding how your computer works, than it does to do with Python.)

"Please don't say "using setuptools, because I have nothing installed other than base Python." - this objection makes no sense. Pip is used to install Setuptools, not the other way around. Setuptools can only install something that's already downloaded - and Pip will in some cases use Setuptools to do its installation after figuring out what to download and downloading it.

"When attempting to install these offline, I've found some good articles, but they require pip. So how do I install pip offline." - before asking how to install Pip, it would have been better to explain why you believed you did not already have it.
